# Google sheets: Get column headers when data is present

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to get column headers based on a filter in table and if the data returns a 1. For example:

```
     ColA ColB ColC  ColD  ColE
Row1           Stat1 Stat2 Stat3
Row2 Bob  Hat  0     0     1
Row3 Bob  Glv  1     1     0
```

So if I have the Filter function:

```
=FILTER(C2:E3, A2:A="Bob", B2:B="Glv")
```

I'd like the return ArrayFormula to be {Stat1, Stat2} (or {Stat3} if the second condition is "Hat").

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use a double `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(C1:E1,--FILTER(C2:E3, A2:A3="Bob", B2:B3="Glv"))
```

Comment: With a minor edit to remove the "--" that works great!  Thanks!

Comment: Removing the "--" in this case gave me the same output as you listed.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you wanted to select a column header where there were one or more 1's in the corresponding column, so came up with

```
=query({transpose(query(FILTER(A2:E, A2:A="Bob", B2:B="Glv"),"select sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5)")),transpose(C1:E1)},"select Col3 where Col2>0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula as the logical expression for an IF nested in ArrayFormula using an empty parameter for the value if false:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(FILTER(C2:E3, A2:A3="Bob", B2:B3="Hat"),C1:E1,))`

The above will return {Stat1,Stat2,}

To remove the empty members of the result array use JOIN and SPLIT:

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(JOIN(",", IF(FILTER(C2:E3, A2:A3="Bob", B2:B3="Hat"), C1:E1,)), ",", FALSE))`